# Why is "this" ok but "this" (in another method) is not?

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is from a c# .net (.aspx.cs) file associated with an aspx file.
Why is "this" ok but "this" (in another method) is not?
i included a snapshot image  to show the red line in the second method to show that the compiler does not like what does not show an error in the first method.

[image]

Comment: Because second method is **static**

Comment: static methods are associated with class instead of instances. this points to the instance of a class and therefore, this in a static method is illegal.

Comment: "Why can't I use `this` in static method?" and it is voted UP?

Answer (score 12):

`this` is used to reference the current instance of a class.
In a static method there is no current instance to reference.

In the first example this references the current instance of the class Resource_Windows_ContractEdit.
In the second example the method is static so it should be called without an instance of the class.  Thus inside that static method you can't use `this`

[C# Reference this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk1507sz.aspx)

A contrived example

```
class Example1
{
     // static. could be used by static methods and it is shared between all instances
     private static int counter = 0;

     // instance variable, exists with different indipendent storage for every instance
     private int v;

     public Example1()
     {
          // We can use the static variable because it is shared between all instances..
          counter = counter + 1;
     }

     public int SumValue(int x)
     {
         // Sum only for the first 10 instances of this class..
         // Yes weird, but it is just a contrived example
         if(Example1.counter < 10)
             this.v = this.v + x:

         return this.v;

     }

     // Cannot use the this keyword neither the instance internal variables
     // Could use the static variables
     public static int GetCurrentInstanceCounter()
     {
         return counter;
     }
}

void Main()
{
    Example1 a = new Example1();

    // a is an instance of class Example1 and could use the this keyword
    int result = a.sumValue(10);
    Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());

    // GetCurrentInstanceCounter is static, no instance required to call it, just the class name 
    int c = Example1.GetCurrentInstanceCounter();
    Console.WriteLine("Created " + c.ToString() + " instances of Example1");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because that's a static method.

The keyword `this` refers to an instance of a type, within the context of non-static method members.

Static members don't belong to any particular instance - they belong to the class itself. So, since there's no instance to refer to, there's no `this`

Answer (score 1):

Since Static member functions exist at the class level and not as part of an object, they do not have a this pointer.

MSDN [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk1507sz.aspx) link